# Can this equation, $Ax=b$ ever have a unique solution where A is a $3\times4$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a rather simple question, but it is throwing me off for some reason. In any case, here's the problem:

\begin{equation} A =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
    2 & -2 & -1 & 4 \\
    3 & -2 & -2 & 3 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Let \begin{equation} b =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    k \\
    3 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

So for what values of $k$ does the system $Ax=b$ have a unique solution? no solution? infinitely many solutions?

Here's what I've done so far. I've reduced the system down to

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr|c}
    1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & k-2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Clearly, there is a free variable. Specifically,

\begin{equation} x =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1-t \\
    (2-k)+2t \\
    (k-2)-2t \\
    t \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

If this is the case, wouldn't it be impossible to have a unique solution? In fact, wouldn't there only be infinite solutions because of the free variable? I don't have the solutions to this problem, so any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; the solution is never unique. To see this, suppose that $x$ is a solution, and $y$ is a solution to 
$$
Ay = 0
$$
Then $x+y$ is also a solution.

Now all I have to show is that $Ay = 0$ always has a nontrivial solution.

Well, a nontrivial solution is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ to comes out to zero. Since $A$ has 4 column vectors in 3-space, they must be linearly dependent, so there's always such a linear combination.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that its impossible for that augmented matrix to have a unique solution. For that to happen, the rank of the row reduced matrix must equal its width, and there just aren't enough rows for that to happen.

By the way, you need to check the first coordinate of your solution $x$. Its not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Set the rhs to 0, you will note non-trivial solutions, which means that the kernel has a dimension larger than $0$. An injective linear mapping however has a kernel with only the null vector as element.